# How to detect if I/O errors are because of HDD fail or other Hardware/Software issues?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, event-log

On my current system I had a **2TB HDD from Segate**, after 2 years Windows started to restart on boot, so I formatted and installed ubuntu. All worked great but after a while I would get I/O errors, something about `/temp`, the system would still be usable you just couldn't start any new tasks. I tried to use the SMART test and it failed executing the test. I tried it on a different computer and it still had issues so I thought it started failing.

I replaced it with a new **CROSAIR Force GS SSD**.

Now my system  keeps getting blue-screens about once every 1-2 days (the computer runs 24/24h), and seem to be hdd related:

- CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION `STOP: 0x000000F4` (during windows update)
- KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR `STOP: 0x0000007A` (during idle at 3am, nothing reported in event viewer)

Is my Mother Board failing? or other Hardware? or am I so unlucky that my new SSD started to fail in the first day?

## UPDATE

Memory check didn't return anything suspicious.
Computer restarted a few times since then (seen an other `STOP: 0x000000F4`) and a new one:

- please insert proper boot device and reboot (also ahci detection takes a lot of time)

Again it's still working after a reboot, so I decided to switch the hdd at an other configuration to see if it's the hdd or the system (MB, RAM, source, etc.), I'll come back with results in a few days.

## UPDATE 2

It's the ssd, I've moved it to a different system and after a day I got the same :

- KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR `STOP: 0x0000007A`
- followed by a bios error, `no boot device detected` (entered in bios after and couldn't see the ssd, after a restart it went back to normal)

so I'll ask a new question: **How to prove that the HDD/SSD is the problem?** What tests can I make so I can get it to fail consistently as now it fails randomly..

Comment: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR can occur because of HDD or RAM. Have you checked your RAM for errors? Press Win+R, type `mdsched.exe`, hit enter. Also check HDD with CheckDisk (read [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/)).

Comment: the hdd is brand new, I'm thinking it should be ok. But I'll do a CheckDisk just to be sure.

Comment: I was also thinking to not be the power supply or the MB that might be causing my hdds to fail, but in Bios all voltages seem stable and consistent.

Comment: I have never in 20+ years working with computers heard of software causing I/O errors. If you are getting I/O errors then its likely caused by hardware.  The new problem is likely caused by a driver conflict.  Can you boot into safe mode?

Comment: @Ramhound The new ssd boots and usually works just fine, I'm working on it right now. I just have a BSOD every once in a while and the only new hardware on my computer is the ssd, and I had Windows 7 before on the old drive, so the only driver that could be misbehaving should be the ssd's.

Comment: Verify you have no memory problems run MemTest86+

Comment: ok it's set for next reboot (I'm guessing mdsched.exe should do the same as MemTest86+)

Comment: `KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR` means the system was unable to read from the paging file, which points to a disk access problem. The other errors indicate the same issue. See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1219285/computer-doesnt-boot-up-shows-pxe-error-and-or-operating-system-not-found

Answer (score 1):

And final answer to:

- Am I so unlucky that my new SSD started to fail in the first day?

Is Yes!

The guys from the store were nice enough to accept it back and send another.